# Regex HTML help

Tags: regex, vb.net

Hey all I'm in need of some help trying to figure out the `RegEx` formula for finding the values within the tags of HTML mark-up like this:

```
<span class=""releaseYear"">1993</span>
<span class=""mpaa"">R</span>
<span class=""average-rating"">2.8</span>
<span class=""rt-fresh-small rt-fresh"" title=""Rotten Tomatoes score"">94%</span>
```

I only need **1993**, **R**, **2.8** and **94%** from that HTML above.

Any help would be great as I don't have much knowledge when it comes to forming one of these things.

Comment: I'd suggest not using regex for a task like this. Read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516811/how-do-you-parse-an-html-in-vb-net) on HTML parsing in .NET.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @Matt Ball - How is it a duplicate?

Comment: @Kobi it's just the archetypal "Don't use regex to parse (X)HTML" question on SO.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a regular expression to parse HTML.  Use an HTML parser.  There is a good one [here](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 3):

If you already have the HTML in a string:

```
string html = @"
<span class=""releaseYear"">1993</span>
<span class=""mpaa"">R</span>
<span class=""average-rating"">2.8</span>
<span class=""rt-fresh-small rt-fresh"" title=""Rotten Tomatoes score"">94%</span>
";
```

Or you can load a page from the internet directly (saves you from 5 lines of streams and requests):

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/source_code/");
```

Using the HTML Agility Pack:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
HtmlNodeCollection spans = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span");
```

Now you can iterate over them, or simply get the text of each node:

```
IEnumerable<string> texts = spans.Select(option => option.InnerText).ToList();
```

Alternatively, you can search for the node you're after:

```
HtmlNode nodeReleaseYear = doc.DocumentNode
                              .SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='releaseYear']");
string year = nodeReleaseYear.InnerText;
```

Comment: The code is C#, but it should be easy enough to convert to VB.Net.

Comment: How do i get it working? I put **HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument()** but it has it underlined saying **HtmlDocument' is a type and cannot be used as an expression** and **Name 'doc' is not declared.**

Comment: @StealthRT, have you added a reference to HtmlAgilityPack in your project?

Comment: @tster. Yes, i have **Imports HtmlAgilityPack**

Comment: @StealthRT - I'm not sure what the VB script should look like. I'd *guess* `Dim doc as new HtmlDocument` . Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516811/how-do-you-parse-an-html-in-vb-net/2604974#2604974