# How to strip all HTML tags and entities and get CLEAR text in Visual Basic?

Tags: html, vb6

How can one who is using Visual Basic (in my case 6), strip all HTML tags and get plain text? I was able to accomplish this with HTML Purifier, but in PHP. Is there a function or a class or a script in VB6 that lets me do this, as I need to process pages over 5MBs and it's really not that efficient in PHP.

So, again, how do I convert this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<div>Section</div>
Hello!
</body>
</html>
```

To, let's say this:

```
Paragraph 1
Section
Hello!
```

I wanted to make an API system to do this, but found out that it's not going to be reliable.

**P.S.:**
I am doing this as I am making a crawler for my search engine, and I only have experience in VB and PHP.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: A simple and naive way would be to search for '<' and '>' and remove the text between them. That will cause problems if you encounter the characters within the tags, though.

Comment: Some inspiration for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516811/how-do-you-parse-an-html-in-vb-net

Comment: How I did this in PHP was remove all tags except (let's say) </div> </p> etc and replaced those with a space (" "). I find regex very confusing but is it the only way?

Comment: BTW I am using VB6 not VB.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have a snipped for C# ... but you can port it to VB very easy :)

```
/// <summary>
/// Remove HTML from string with Regex.
/// </summary>
public static string StripTagsRegex(string source)
{
            return Regex.Replace(source, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: And `<title>Title</title>`?

Comment: only the title node exists? ... this RegEx you use replace all tags that starts with < and end with > with an empty string ... i'm really confused that the title node will not be replaced ...

Comment: No I have not tried this I am just wondering if it removes the title?

Comment: yes! it removes the title node ... but if you want to build a crawler, why you are not using the HtmlAgilityPack? ... Its a library that can really nice things with the Html Code ...

Comment: Yup, you gave me a nice idea of just running several regexes in my app and removing Comments/Tags/CSS/Scripts etc. It works decently I just need to make sure its not xss vulnerable.

Comment: Does not filter out multiline block elements like script or style tags.

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is old, but I wrote this today. It isn't elegant, but it works great.

```
    Public Function RemoveHTML(HTMLstring As String) As String

        IF NOT HTMLstring.contains("<") THEN return HTMLstring

        Dim DoRec As Boolean = False
        Dim textOut As String = ""

        Dim SkipMe As Boolean = False
        Dim SkipMeTag As String = ""

        For l = 1 To HTMLstring.Length
            Dim tmp As String = Mid(HTMLstring, l, 1)

            ' Enable skip-me mode (for large blocks of non-readable code)
            If tmp = "<" And Mid(HTMLstring, l + 1, 6) = "script" Then SkipMe = True : SkipMeTag = "script" : DoRec = False
            If tmp = "<" And Mid(HTMLstring, l + 1, 5) = "style" Then SkipMe = True : SkipMeTag = "style" : DoRec = False

            ' If we're already in skip-me mode, then figure out iff it's time to exit it.
            If SkipMe = True Then
                If tmp = "<" And Mid(HTMLstring, l + 1, Len(SkipMeTag) + 1) = "/" + SkipMeTag Then
                    SkipMe = False
                    tmp = ""
                    l = l + Len(SkipMeTag) + 1
                    DoRec = False
                End If
            End If

            ' If we arent in skip-me mode, move on to handle parsing of the HTML content (pulling text out from in between tags)
            If SkipMe = False Then
                If tmp = ">" Then DoRec = True : textOut &= " " : tmp = ""
                If tmp = "<" Then DoRec = False : tmp = ""

                If DoRec = True Then
                    textOut &= tmp
                End If
            End If

        Next

        Return textOut
    End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much it saved my time. but it was not compatible with vb6. i have downgraded your code and added here as an answer

Comment: There is an important bug in this function. if it doesn't find any html tag in your variable, it returns empty value! To be safe, use something like this condition: if len(RemoveHTML(variable))>0 then variable=RemoveHTML(variable)

Answer (score 2):

@Matth3w Code was great but was not Compatible With (VB6 - Visual Basic 6)

I have downgraded his code to vb6 and also added some useful extra codes to it

1) If your HTML Texts contains Unicode (UTF-8) characters, Add (Microsoft Forms 2 Object Library) and use its (Textbox) for the (input and output)

2) Add 2 Textboxes and 1 Command Button

3) Set the textboxes properties: (MultiLine=true) (change font to Tahoma or something which is not: Ms Sans Serif) (Scrollbars: 3)

4) Paste the following code to the code area:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    TextBox2.Text = RemoveHTML(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub

Public Function RemoveHTML(HTMLstring As String) As String

    Dim DoRec As Boolean
    Dim textOut As String

    Dim SkipMe As Boolean
    Dim SkipMeTag As String

    Dim tmp As String

    HTMLstring = Replace(LCase(HTMLstring), "</p>", vbCrLf)
    HTMLstring = Replace(LCase(HTMLstring), "<br>", vbCrLf)
    HTMLstring = Replace(LCase(HTMLstring), "<br/>", vbCrLf)
    HTMLstring = Replace(LCase(HTMLstring), "&zwnj;", " ")
    HTMLstring = Replace(LCase(HTMLstring), "&nbsp;", " ")

    HTMLstring = Replace(LCase(HTMLstring), "&sect;", "-")
    HTMLstring = Replace(LCase(HTMLstring), "&ndash;", "-")
    HTMLstring = Replace(LCase(HTMLstring), "&mdash;", "-")
    HTMLstring = Replace(LCase(HTMLstring), "&rlm;", "")
    HTMLstring = Replace(LCase(HTMLstring), "&ldquo;", ChrW(34))
    HTMLstring = Replace(LCase(HTMLstring), "&rdquo;", ChrW(34))
    HTMLstring = Replace(LCase(HTMLstring), "&lsquo;", ChrW(34))
    HTMLstring = Replace(LCase(HTMLstring), "&rsquo;", ChrW(34))

    HTMLstring = Replace(LCase(HTMLstring), "&laquo;", ChrW(34))
    HTMLstring = Replace(LCase(HTMLstring), "&raquo;", ChrW(34))

    For l = 1 To Len(HTMLstring)
        tmp = Mid(HTMLstring, l, 1)

        ' Enable skip-me mode (for large blocks of non-readable code)
        If tmp = "<" And Mid(HTMLstring, l + 1, 6) = "script" Then SkipMe = True: SkipMeTag = "script": DoRec = False
        If tmp = "<" And Mid(HTMLstring, l + 1, 5) = "style" Then SkipMe = True: SkipMeTag = "style": DoRec = False

        ' If we're already in skip-me mode, then figure out iff it's time to exit it.
        If SkipMe = True Then
            If tmp = "<" And Mid(HTMLstring, l + 1, Len(SkipMeTag) + 1) = "/" + SkipMeTag Then
                SkipMe = False
                tmp = ""
                l = l + Len(SkipMeTag) + 1
                DoRec = False
            End If
        End If

        ' If we arent in skip-me mode, move on to handle parsing of the HTML content (pulling text out from in between tags)
        If SkipMe = False Then
            If tmp = ">" Then DoRec = True: textOut = textOut & " ": tmp = ""
            If tmp = "<" Then DoRec = False: tmp = ""

            If DoRec = True Then
                textOut = textOut & tmp
            End If
        End If

    Next

    RemoveHTML = textOut
End Function
```

(To Support Persian Language)
To change Old Farsi ي To New One ی You can add this line:

```
HTMLstring = Replace(LCase(HTMLstring), ChrW(1610), ChrW(1740))
```

**Update:** There is an important bug in this function. if it doesn't find any html tag in your variable, it returns empty value! To be safe, use something like this condition:

```
if len(RemoveHTML(variable))>0 then variable=RemoveHTML(variable)
```

Comment: There is an important bug in this function. if it doesn't find any html tag in your variable, it returns empty value! To be safe, use something like this condition: if len(RemoveHTML(variable))>0 then variable=RemoveHTML(variable)

Answer (score 1):

Considering how flawed most HTML you find can be, I find it much easier to use a technique like that described in [HTML Parsing? Tidy it up first](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?643977-VB6-HTML-Parsing-Tidy-it-up-first).

The cleaned up HTML is then suitable for parsing using any of several techniques, from loading it into an XML DOM, to using a SAX parser, to hand-coded parsing, to regular expressions (if you insist on making your life and the lives of any maintainers who come after you difficult).

If your documents are of reasonably small size the DOM is the easy way to go.  After loading the cleaned HTML as XML you can simply walk the node tree extracting any non-empty `text` properties.  It is easy to use an exclusion list of `nodeName` or `baseName` values for tags to be ignored.

Comment: I thought that VB6 was a good idea, but I was wrong. I will just use HTMLPurifier in PHP and make it sort of like an API, because there are just too many things to do in VB6.

Comment: Strange comment since there isn't much to it.  Have you considered hiring a VB6 programmer?