# How do i get a certain piece of text from a webpage using vb.net 2008?

Tags: vb.net

I need to get a certain piece of text from a webpage and display it in a label, i have searched and haven't found anything i understand very well, im pretty sure i will have to use getelementbyid but i'm not sure

Comment: i only want a certain piece of text from the webpage though ?

Comment: Your question is quite vague and if you provide more detail someone would be able to give you assistance. Are you creating a Windows form app, ASP.net app etc? Is the text you're grabbing from the same page you want to display it on?

Comment: im creating a windows form and i just want to get the text from a webpage and display it as a label on the form

Answer (score 0):

Check out [HttpClient.GetStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient.getstringasync.aspx). You'll need to pull down the contents of the page at the given URL and then [parse the contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516811/how-do-you-parse-an-html-in-vb-net) for the field you want.

After that, displaying the value in the label is pretty straight forward. Give it a shot and if you run into problems post a specific question with code and you'll get a lot of help.