# how to extract HTML table contents to DataTable

Tags: c#, html, vb.net, parsing, href

I have [this](http://pastebin.com/NGrTKt0j) html page and the contents in the page looks like below

[image]

I'm trying to fetch the contents in the page into a DataTable and display it to a grid

for example in

```
<a href='/exodus-5.1/bacon/exodus-5.1-20150612-NIGHTLY-bacon.zip'>exodus-5.1-20150612-NIGHTLY-bacon.zip</a>
```

I need to get the name of the link as well as the uri too

name : - *exodus-5.1-20150612-NIGHTLY-bacon.zip*
uri : - `/exodus-5.1/bacon/exodus-5.1-20150612-NIGHTLY-bacon.zip`

following is what I have ended up

```
 Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
 request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get
 Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
 Dim reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
 Dim webpageContents As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
 response.Close()
```

Comment: Now that you have the contents of the page, you'll need to [parse it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516811/how-do-you-parse-an-html-in-vb-net). After you scrape the required info, you can [add it to your DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not VB.Net this is a very easy task to achieve using another .Net language F# and the [HTML Type Provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/HtmlProvider.html) which is part of the [FSharp.Data project](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/index.html) available via Nuget.

The HTML Type Provider gives you typed access to HTML documents inside Visual Studio, i.e.

```
// Reference the FSharp.Data Nuget package
#r @".\packages\FSharp.Data.2.2.3\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll"
// Type provider over your HTML document specified in yourUrl
type html = FSharp.Data.HtmlProvider<yourUrl>
// Get the rows from the HTML table in the page
let allRows = html.GetSample().Tables.Table1.Rows |> Seq.skip 1
// Skip empty rows
let validRows = allRows |> Seq.where (fun row -> row.Name <> "")
```

Then load the valid rows into a DataTable:

```
// Reference the System.Data assembly
#r "System.Data.dll"
// Create a DataTable
let table = new System.Data.DataTable()
// Add column names to the table
for name in ["Parent";"Name";"Last modified";"Size"] do table.Columns.Add(name) |> ignore
// Add row values to the table
for row in validRows do
  table.Rows.Add(row.Column1, row.Name, row.``Last modified``, row.Size) |> ignore
```

and finally show the DataTable on a form:

```
// Reference the Windows.Forms assembly
#r "System.Windows.Forms.dll"
open System.Windows.Forms
// Create a form
let form = new Form(Width=480,Height=320)
// Initialise a grid
let grid = new DataGridView(Dock=DockStyle.Fill)
form.Controls.Add(grid)
// Set the grid data source with the table
form.Load.Add(fun _ -> grid.DataSource <- table)
form.Show()
```

Which shows a populated DataGrid in a form:

[image: DataTable]