# Regex is not matching all alternate groups

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

The input string is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="locale" value="us">
```

The regex pattern is:

```
Dim r As New Regex("<input\s{0,}(?:(name|type|value)=""([^""]+)""\s{0,})+>")
```

The code being used:

```
        If r.IsMatch(s) Then
            For Each m As Match In r.Matches(s)
                Debug.Print(m.ToString)
                For i As Integer = 0 To m.Groups.Count - 1
                    Debug.Print(New String(" "c, i + 1) & "-" & m.Groups(i).Value)
                Next
            Next
        End If
```

The output:

```
<input type="hidden" name="locale" value="us">
 -<input type="hidden" name="locale" value="us">
  -value
   -us
```

I would expect it to match:

```
-type
-hidden
-name
-locale
-value
-us
```

The alternate pattern used goes by the order it is provided in, perhaps that's why it's only spitting out one group, which is the last match.

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Comment: I've heard similar disputes before. Just because it's difficult, I refuse to believe there isn't a regex junkie that can tackle this.

Comment: It's not a matter of being *difficult*: It's that HTML is so complex that a *proper* regex would be *huge*.

Comment: I only want to match this string, not a whole HTML page. To help your point, I know this could easily be parsed out using .IndexOf and .Substring, etc.

Comment: Yeah. And then it changes the quotes to `'`. Or adds some whitespace around the `=`. Or a value-less attribute shows up. Do you see where I'm going?

Comment: Gotcha, point taken. A complex pattern it would be but not impossible. I still have faith.

Comment: Your presumption is wrong, your regex matches all the groups. Not only  does it match the groups, but also *captures*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good idea to parse HTML data with regex. Use HtmlAgilityPack or similar libraries that are meant to do this. See [How do you parse an HTML in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516811/how-do-you-parse-an-html-in-vb-net).

Answering your question, you do not access the *captures* that are all stored in the capture collection in each group. Here is a simple snippet showing how to obtain your desired result using *the same* regex:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim r As New Regex("<input\s{0,}(?:(name|type|value)=""([^""]+)""\s{0,})+>")
        Dim s As String
        s = "<input type=""hidden"" name=""locale"" value=""us"">"
        If r.IsMatch(s) Then
            For Each m As Match In r.Matches(s)
                Console.WriteLine(m.ToString)
                For j As Integer = 0 To m.Groups(1).Captures.Count - 1      ' Number of captures in Capture stack 1 (same will be in the second one)
                    Console.WriteLine(" -" & m.Groups(1).Captures(j).Value) ' Print the 1st group captures
                    Console.WriteLine(" -" & m.Groups(2).Captures(j).Value) ' Print the 2nd group captures
                Next
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Output:

```
<input type="hidden" name="locale" value="us">
 -type
 -hidden
 -name
 -locale
 -value
 -us
```

See the [VB.NET demo](https://ideone.com/8ODNFb)