# How to download HtmlAgilityPack directly (ZIP or DLL without NuGet)?

Tags: nuget, html-agility-pack

Really, the author simply took and removed links to direct download? I don't understand this. Maybe MS paid him for advertising NuGet?

Comment: haha reading now and laughing at myself. how i was too emotional.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse an HTML in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516811/how-do-you-parse-an-html-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/)

CodePlex will be shutting down, so keeping a version up to date on it doesn't make sense. In fact, it's still currently possible to download the v1.4.6 (not the latest) on CodePlex: https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

HtmlAgilityPack (HAP) Binaries are now available for download only from NuGet.

This has been done as a standard as well as ease of maintenance.

If you want to download the sourcecode and compile, you still can do it by downloading the source from GitHub: 
https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack